# How to display values from Json encode using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my code to get number of notifications that the user has to read

```
<script>

var strBuilder = [];

$.ajax({
  url: "/php/getnotications.php",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(index,obj){

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(valor)) 
    {
        strBuilder.push("Key is " + valor +"\n");
    }else{
        strBuilder.push("error");
    }

    $("#get-not").append(obj.count(id));
        alert(strBuilder.join(""));
    });
    },

    error: function(result)
    {
        console.log(result);
    }
})

</script>
```

This is the Object of Json:

```
[{"count(id)":"3"}]
```

In `console.log` I receive

> Object

Comment: You could [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your object before displaying it

Comment: If the log is from the `error` something is wrong with the request. Use the error arguments to get more details

Comment: @charlietfl gets undefined in error statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to get '3':

```
console.log(result["count(id)"]);
```

Or if you want all JSON as a string:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: is perfectly valid json, first statement not true

Comment: Where did you add this code? Try adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` as the first line of the success callback function and then inspect the structure.

Comment: Also `result` is an array, not an object

Comment: @JcoderMan the main idea, I think, that you get console output, so you it outputs the `result` of error callback function here: error: function(result){ console.log(result); } Otherwise you'd get an alert.